# Neural Network is overfitting when using bigger dataset

Tags: neural-network, overfitting

I'm tring to train a model using CNN (supervised) to solve a binary classification problem. I have pretty big dataset containing 2 800 000 samples, each having 100+ features. Because training with such big dataset takes about 20 hours I've built my net with using only 25% of dataset (about 700 000 samples). And if model have promising resoults on smaller dataset, then use full dataset to train.

Here is something strange. I get pretty good resoults when using 25% of dataset
[image]

It looks realy good, so I decided to train a model with using full dataset, and i get this[image]
which is awful. Model is clearly overfitting.
I don't have much experience with machine learning, but as far as I know, one way to solve overfit problem is to increase dataset. But here, problem with overfiting occures only when I use bigger dataset. Other way to solve it would be to decrease number of layers, or number of neurons, but the same CNN have trained a good model on smaller dataset. 
My CNN looks like this
2 x Linear Layer
1 x Convolution
2 x Linear
4 x Convolution
6 x Linear

And before every linear layer there is a dropout 50%, and dropout 20% is on input. And after every Convolution there is also a Avg pooling layer.
Because dataset is pretty big, batch size is 256 for now. 
One of my ideas is to increase a batch size to 512, or even 1024 when training with full dataset, or to add a batch normalization layers, but before I do that, I want to ask for your advices, because, as I said, training takes about 20 hours...

EDIT.
I collect data on every 1% of batches. So data is collected 100 times for each epoch. Model is trained on 100 epochs, so data are collected 10000 times, and this value is on x axis.
Also, to bad but I unfortunetly can not share the code.

Comment: May I know what does your x-axis on your plot represents? One thing that you might not notice is that you might be comparing a model that is trained 4 times more. To put it simply image like you are evaluating after every epoch(500 iterations on 25% dataset) but on full dataset this will be 2000 terations which is a huge difference, and your evaluation might be misleading, so at 500 it hasn't overfitted but on 2000 it overfitted. If your sample correctly, what I feel right now your original 25 percent, might have the tendency to overfit, but as far as your training went it just haven't happen.

Comment: could you also share the model structure directly, instead of describing it? You can edit the question to add your code.

Comment: @YohanesAlfredo this is a very usefull comment! Thank you.
If I understand it correctly, decreasing number of epochs, or increasing batch size will decrease number of iterations, and would help me catch a moment when net starts to be overfit. 
And second question I have. If i'm having good resoult when using only 25% of dataset to train, than what is the point of using full dataset? Could I jest leave it as it is, and use remaining 75% of data to validate the net?

Comment: It has something to do with generalization power, but I think for neural network it is always a blessing to have more data, but this is only true **given** your model has the capacity to learn it, otherwise you will not observe any significant improvements. I think to verify this you can try something like this. Holdout a fraction of your dataset say 20%, now you experiment with two models, one that is trained with 20% of your data, another one with the full 80%. I think this is a good way to compare the generalization power of both models.

Comment: Some interesting paper that quite highlights the advantage of having more data https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.00932.pdf